# While resolving: @typegoose/typegoose@7.2.0 npm ERR! Found: mongoose@6.0.6 node_modules mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, mongoose

I'm new to microservices linking and I'm trying to link project `backend-common` to another project. To do that, I'm doing the following:

1. `npm link`
2. `npm link mongoose`

But when I'm trying to link mongoose I'm getting an error:

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @typegoose/typegoose@7.2.0
npm ERR! Found: mongoose@6.0.6
npm ERR! node_modules/mongoose
npm ERR!   mongoose@"file:../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoose" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer mongoose@"^5.9.17" from @typegoose/typegoose@7.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@typegoose/typegoose
npm ERR!   @typegoose/typegoose@"7.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: mongoose@5.13.9
npm ERR! node_modules/mongoose
npm ERR!   peer mongoose@"^5.9.17" from @typegoose/typegoose@7.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@typegoose/typegoose
npm ERR!     @typegoose/typegoose@"7.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

It seems that I have different versions of mongoose, but for some reason my project trying to read mongoose from another directory that (i think) does not belong to project.

Files `package.json` and `package-lock.json` have exactly that the same versions.

Commands like: `npm-fuck` and `npm-fuck suka` do not work for it. It is just reset `package.json`, `package-lock.json`, and `node_modules`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED:] The main problem was with node.js environment. I had `node.js version: 12`

But `node.js version: 14` is required.

If you have a similar problem, do the following steps:

1. Check your `node.js version` with `node -v`
2. `npm cache clean -f`
3. `sudo npm install -g n`
4. `sudo n stable`
5. And again check your version of node.js with `node -v`